# Websocket Wss connection failed

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, protocols, java-websocket

everyone. I'm trying to apply the websocket to our server.

I used the websocket provided by Javax, succeeded in connecting in my local environment, and sent a message to the client.

However, as a result of applying it to the server, the connection is failing. The difference from the local environment is that the protocol uses wss instead of ws.

Currently, our server is using SSL. Is it related to this?

Please Help.
Please help!

Code at client side (Javascript)

````
```
var protocol = location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss:' : 'ws:';
var hostPort = location.host;
var webSocket = new WebSocket(protocol+"//"+hostPort+$B.path+"/websocket");
```
````

Code at Server side (Java)

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class WebSocket {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(WebSocket.class);
    public static Session session;
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        String username = "";
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("You are connected. Your ID is" + session);
            // sessions.put("",session);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error on open web socket", e);
        }
    }
```

Error at the browser console :

```
VM1435:4 WebSocket connection to 'wss://framptest.bizflow.com/bizflowappdev/websocket' failed:
```

Comment: I tried  like below.   

`var webSocket = new WebSocket(protocol+"//"+hostPort+$B.path+"/websocket", {
  protocolVersion: 8,
  origin: protocol+"//"+hostPort+$B.path+"/websocket",
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});`

it's show this error : Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I already solves this problem.
It's related with apache.

I add proxypass `localhost:8080/websocketPath` to http conf file.

That result, I success connect using wss protocol.